# Passing arguments on os.system call in Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg

I want to chop an audio file into equal 20 second pieces and would like to rename the output files as fname0.wav, fname1.wav, etc. How can I achieve this? Using the following I get the error:

[image]

Comment: You have three arguments in your format string - %s, %s, and %09d. But you’re only passing in two variables.

Comment: thanks, I see that but what would be the 3rd variable? I am passing 'file' to the first %s argument, and passing the 'fname' to the second %s, I don`t know what to pass for %09d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran a test with ffmpeg and this worked:

```
cmd2 = "ffmpeg -i %s -f segment -segment_time 20 -c copy %s" %(file, fname) + "%09d.wav"
os.system(cmd2)
```

You leave "%09d.wav" as it is and put it at the end of the string, outside the formatting.

Comment: hi, thanks, this is helpful but didn`t work. I need to know the number of segments which is 20 in your solution. I checked the total length of the file which is 22.82525 sn. Now this brought a new question: when python chop the file in equal pieces does it through away the left over? For this specific file 'for i in range(?)' what that would be just zero?

Comment: I don't understand. The output files are 22.8 seconds long even if you tell it 20 seconds?

Comment: I think the last section will just be shorter. I don't think it will throw it away. Try it and see what happens.

Comment: No, i meant the sample file i want to chop was only 22.8 sn itself. So it should be one 20 sn piece and one 0.8 sn piece if it does`nt through away, but then they won`t be equal pieces, confusing. I did try your solution, it did not create any file, thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you try it again now. I accidentally put the segment time as 29 initially, but now I've corrected the answer. Maybe it didn't create a file because it was asking for a length longer than the length of the file.

Comment: %d is not to be parsed by python. It is a format specifier for ffmpeg's segmenter which will evaluate and fill it as each segment is created.

Comment: thanks, actually i noticed that typo 29 and corrected it before I tried the code.

Comment: I just did a test with ffmpeg and I've changed my answer to something that actually works. Please accept if that answers your question.